# How does Spread know to update image in Kubernetes?

Tags: docker, kubernetes, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner, spread

I want to set up a Gitlab CD to Kubernetes and I read this [article](https://about.gitlab.com/2016/03/22/gitlab-8-6-released/)

However, I am wondering, how is it that my K8 cluster would be updated with my latest Docker images?

For example, in my `.gitlab-ci.yaml` file I will have a `build`, `test`, and `release` stage that ultimately updates my cloud Docker images. By setting up the `deploy` stage as instructed in the article:

```
deploy:
  stage: deploy
  image: redspreadapps/gitlabci
  script:
  - null-script
```

would Spread then know to "magically" update my K8 cluster (perhaps by repulling all images, perform `rolling-update`s) as long as I set up my directory structure of K8 resources as is [specified](https://redspread.readme.io/docs/getting-started) by Spread?

Answer (score 1):

I don't have a direct answer, but from looking at the spread project it seems pretty dead. Last commit in Aug last year with a bunch of issues and not supporting any of the newer kubernetes constructs (e.g. deployments).

The typical way to update images in kubernetes nowadays is to run a command like `kubectl set image <deployment-name> <image>`. This will in turn perform a rolling update on the deployment and shutting down a POD at a time updating it with the new image. See this [doc](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/deployment/).

Since spread is from before that, I assume they must use rolling update replication controller with a command like `kubectl rolling-update NAME -f FILE` and picking up the new image from the configuration file in their project folder (assuming it changed). See this [doc](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/run-application/rolling-update-replication-controller/).